# Hello, I'm trying to create tables in oracle sqlplus, but I keep getting an invalid datatype error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Plays (    playId INT PRIMARY KEY,    gameId INT,    playNumber INT,    quarter INT,    time TIMESTAMP,    yardLine INT,    possessionTeam VARCHAR2(10),    playType VARCHAR2(10),    yardGain INT,    yardsToGo INT,    down INT,    distance INT,    yardsToEndzone INT,    scoreDiff INT,    epa REAL,    isRush BOOLEAN,    isPass BOOLEAN,    isIncomplete BOOLEAN,    isTouchdown BOOLEAN,    passType VARCHAR2(10),    passLocation VARCHAR2(10),    rushDirection VARCHAR2(10),    rushLocation VARCHAR2(10),    receiver VARCHAR2(20),    defender VARCHAR2(20));
```

> CREATE TABLE Plays (    playId INT PRIMARY KEY,    gameId INT,
> playNumber INT,    quarter INT,    time TIMESTAMP,    yardLine INT,
> possessionTeam VARCHAR2(10),    playType VARCHAR2(10),    yardGain
> INT,    yardsToGo INT,    down INT,    distance INT,    yardsToEndzone
> INT,    scoreDiff INT,    epa REAL,        isRush BOOLEAN,    isPass
> BOOLEAN,        isIncomplete BOOLEAN,    isTouchdown BOOLEAN,
> passType VARCHAR2(10),    passLocation VARCHAR2(10),    rushDirection
> VARCHAR2(10),    rushLocation VARCHAR2(10),    receiver VARCHAR2(20),
> defender VARCHAR2(20))
> *
>
> ERROR at line 1:
>  ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Tried to create sql table but got an invalid datatype error but from my side everything seems fine

Comment: Seems like you're trying to use an invalid data type. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: In Oracle you cannot use BOOLEAN datatype. Instead of it try to use the char(1) datatype.

Comment: Char(1) works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`BOOLEAN` is not a valid Oracle SQL data-type. (It is a valid data-type in PL/SQL.)

You can use a different data-type such as `CHAR(1)` or `NUMBER(1,0)` and add check constraints to restrict it to `'Y'`/`'N'` or `1`/`0`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Plays (
    playId         INT PRIMARY KEY,
    gameId         INT,
    playNumber     INT,
    quarter        INT,
    time           TIMESTAMP,
    yardLine       INT,
    possessionTeam VARCHAR2(10),
    playType       VARCHAR2(10),
    yardGain       INT,
    yardsToGo      INT,
    down           INT,
    distance       INT,
    yardsToEndzone INT,
    scoreDiff      INT,
    epa            REAL,
    isRush         CHAR(1) CHECK (isRush IN ('Y', 'N')),
    isPass         CHAR(1) CHECK (isPass IN ('Y', 'N')),
    isIncomplete   CHAR(1) CHECK (isIncomplete IN ('Y', 'N')),
    isTouchdown    CHAR(1) CHECK (isTouchdown IN ('Y', 'N')),
    passType       VARCHAR2(10),
    passLocation   VARCHAR2(10),
    rushDirection  VARCHAR2(10),
    rushLocation   VARCHAR2(10),
    receiver       VARCHAR2(20),
    defender       VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x8_4ysiK)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you cannot use BOOLEAN datatype.

A valid create statement is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Plays
(playId INT PRIMARY KEY,
 gameId INT,
 playNumber INT,
 quarter INT,
 time TIMESTAMP,
 yardLine INT,
 possessionTeam VARCHAR2(10),
 playType VARCHAR2(10),
 yardGain INT,
 yardsToGo INT,
 down INT,
 distance INT,
 yardsToEndzone INT,
 scoreDiff INT,
 epa REAL,
 isRush char(1),
 isPass char(1),
 isIncomplete char(1),
 isTouchdown char(1),
 passType VARCHAR2(10),
 passLocation VARCHAR2(10),
 rushDirection VARCHAR2(10),
 rushLocation VARCHAR2(10),
 receiver VARCHAR2(20),
 defender VARCHAR2(20));
```